# Is a suicidal person who continues to live disproving/contradicting determinism?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-science, determinism, life

Consider someone who has repeatedly considered suicide, but who does not carry it out. There are two ways you can look at this (for the sake of argument here at least):

1.The person doesn't do it because they have free will and choose not to;

2.The person hasn't done it or yet or will never do it because of determinism.

People can clearly choose to look at this in further ways:

> An action not yet taken could be taken at some point; hence, the person may one day end their life.
>
> The person has a destiny and unseen forces don't allow him/her to commit suicide.
>
> They are afraid of killing their self. Cause and effect can explain this; therefore, it's deterministic because that inherent fear is what prevents the action and does not let the person commit suicide.
>
> If a person really wanted to end their own life, they would; if not, their will to do so isn't powerful enough, and once again this can be attributed to a deterministic view of the universe.

The idea is that, no matter what action they take, it is justified somehow or explained some way.

If they didn't kill themselves, people would say that they are not determined to do it; or that cause and effect and/or determinism has something to do with it; but if they did do it, the same thing can be said.

If we argue that any outcome is the same, it's believing the universe is chaotic ***and*** predictable.

Arguing that committing suicide or not is a destiny would be the same as inverse-forward logic: figuring that something NOT true can be, but something that IS true won't be because it's false.

Comment: Can you make clearer what the specific question you have about philosophy for us that is answerable within the SE format?

Comment: A person who is suicidal is not determined to end their own life, they are just a person who is unhappy with their life. Even if they make statements like 'I want to die', that doesn't necessarily mean they actually want to die, even if that fact is unknown even to them. This means that your question isn't completely coherent.

Comment: Yes, anything we observe can be reconciled with both determinism and intederminism, they are empirically unfalsifiable. It does not amount to believing that the universe is chaotic and predictable, there are chaotic dynamical systems which are deterministic and unpredictable, because arbitrarily small variations lead to widely diverging outcomes. Since we can not measure to infinite precision we can not predict them, see [chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory)

Comment: Unclear, conflicting or changing desires have nothing to do with determinism.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong about the definition of determinism, it means that the course of action of anything in the universe is predetermined. For inanimate objects, such as a chemical reaction this is true always as it will follow a path such that the entropy of the system is decreased, however as soon as we are faced with an animate object or an object which has free-will (discussed later) we are faced with a few problems.

Objects with a free-will have a tendency to perform in order to attain a particular set of goal, that can be proving a point or reaching a certain level of satisfaction, happiness; hence we can argue that their will is not so free after all; because the action of 'people' are determined by a set of boundaries:

1. Desire (the end goal)
2. Environmental effects (situations and all)
3. Will-power
4. Capability

(A few factors might have been missed out as well)
In the end we are similar to a chemical reaction in which everything is prejudged or **determined**.
However, the points 3, 4 can be changed by making their improvement an end goal. Improving point 3,4 will automatically affect point 2 and will make our environment more favorable to the end goal. Hence, the universe with all its inanimate and animate objects is deterministic **but** we can change the equations or the factors governing the determinism.

*if you want I can try a case study for the particular suicide case as well. :)*

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be presuming that anyone who is "suicidal" should have successfully killed themselves. There is no such casual link - having suicidal thoughts and even attempting suicide, does not mean that one is predestined to do so.

Can one violate predestination by simply changing their mind? Surely it's not that easy.

Before exploring whether your example breaks determinism you need to establish more clearly what it would mean for any example to do so. Just having a though and not going through with it in no way disproves (or proves) determinism. Remember that your thoughts are (determinism posits) the result of electrochemical interactions in your brain. Just like your actions, these can be causally linked back to the beginning of time in a purely physical universe. There's no requirement that Thought A lead to Action B.

The standard solution to disproving determinism and/or establishing free will is to identify something "extra" about free-beings, such as a soul, that transcends physics. If your philosophical thesis (or religion) grants humans' souls then humans are not limited by physical limitations like causality. Unless you're willing to grant humans some extra-physical characteristic it will be difficult to disprove determinism.

Comment: @JohnAm sorry what? Electrochemical reactions are physical processes, whether they're forces or not doesn't grant free will.

Comment: Chemical reactions are a specific type of psychical process. The laws of physics still apply to chemistry.

Comment: No, they don't. The laws of physics apply *always*, that's why they're called laws.

Comment: Look, Chemistry doesn't disprove Determinism, and Compatibilism has nothing to do with Chemistry. I've no problem with Compatibalism, but it does not ride upon "neuron systems [not acting] according to forces but according to electrochemical reactions". Your original comment remains nonsensical.

Comment: I'm fully aware of copatabalism as a theory. Your chemistry example, however, is not a coherent form of compatibalism.